Google Fit API - Health Connect | Smooth transition
I have an app that reads step data from the Google Fit APIs that are being deprecated in 2025, and am looking to make the transition to using Health Connect.
I can access Health Connect with no problem - the user can give the new permission and I can read data from the new datasource without issue.
However, for the data to sync from Google Fit to Health Connect, the user has to go into the Google Fit settings and switch on "Sync Fit with Health Connect".
This is a horrible user experience, and seems unnecessary - I would expect this sync to happen automatically for a smooth transition between APIs.
Does anyone have any information about this, or can anyone tell me what I'm missing?
